# Need to run a php file in my site

Tags: php

I have a .php file to send mail from my website. How I can run the php file in my domain ? Do I need to install any server in my domain space ?

Comment: Do you host the domain yourself?

Comment: Seems you need to learn the basics of php first. just google `Learn Php` and you will get all those stuffs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes! Your server must run some php interpreter , that in this case will be the [Apache Server](http://apache.org).

Also you have to configure his modules to send mail also.

In must of hosting servers Apache is free and   It's already installed.

Answer (score 0):

Create a file with filename 'test.php'

Put following code in it:

```
<?php

echo 'test';

?>
```

Upload the file to your server

Open it in Browser via http://yourdomain.tld/test.php

Does it show the word test?

Comment: Hi, Thanks for reply. It is working. I am able to send mail. But the php file is not retrieving the data from my html form. Instead I am getting empty mail in my inbox. What could be possible reasons ?.. I have verified the html tags ID and the IDs in the php page...  Please help

Comment: <input name="message"> in a form will send a Variable to the Server that can be used in PHP referencing $_REQUEST['message']. BUT! I highly recommend that you don't build a mail form! Simply don't do it! Spammers will use it and you will get problems! Learn PHP first.